# Is message queueing mandatory for Azure web app when sending emails through SendGrid

Tags: asp.net, azure, message-queue, sendgrid

I have an Azure web application (Asp.net MVC & WebAPI) that sends emails through SendGrid service. I'm not using SendGrid's API but rather use .net built-in SMTP that I configured in web.config and directed to SendGrid.

I'm now wondering whether I also need message queueing application in my solution that would be used to actually send emails to SendGrid to minimize request/response times of my web app?

Azure already has Queue Storage that I could use but I wonder how others have implemented this? I'm also looking for the most simple example of Azure web app using queueing if one exists.

I expect message queueing will become relevant when I'll have several emails to send during single request to make my app scalable. Currently I'm sending email synchronously when my backend executes code and so far with the low number of emails it works fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your application need to manage and send bulk emails asynchronously, it would be better to have separate application which will take emails as bulk.

In my recent project, I have created separate application using web role, worker role and a service bus queue. Web role is a web API which used for application to post bulk emails and put it into a service bus queue. Then worker role will be responsible for dealing with the queues and send the emails. This allowed me to send emails asynchronously and storing any email messages or message status in a table storage.

Further, this approach helps me to use same notification application (email sending application) in different projects by using a wrapper to handle web api integration.

Comment: We are in development stage, the whole idea is to support volume. This application will be facilitate large number of bulk emails (thousands), currently it could be around 300, but we can increase the number of worker roles in order to support large number of batch emails.